# Random repetition function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, random, coordinates

I would like to generate a random repetition of my function Robot.prototype.seDeplacer

this function give a random move to my robots (coordinates) but I want to create a random repetition of the random move.
How is it possible?

I don't want a timer or something like that, just repeat 1, 2 or 3 times the random move from my Robot.prototype.seDeplacer function.

I hope I'm enough clear.

Thank you very much

```
// Objet Robot
function Robot(nick, pv, maxSpeed, position) {
 this.nick = nick;
 this.pv = pv;
 this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
 this.position = position;
};

//Méthode présentation des robots
Robot.prototype.sePresenter = function() {
 console.log("Bonjour je m'appelle " + this.nick + ". J'ai " + this.pv + " points de vie." + " Je me déplace à " + this.maxSpeed + " cases par seconde. Je suis à la case de coordonnées " + this.position);
};
Robot.prototype.seDeplacer = function() {
 if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
 // mouvement sur l'axe x
 } else {
 // mouvement sur l'axe y
 }
 var dx = (Math.random() * this.maxSpeed * 2) - this.maxSpeed;
 this.position[0] += dx;

 console.log("J'avancer vers " + this.position)
};

//Variables array
var robots = [
 new Robot('Maurice',95,2,[5,8]),
 new Robot('Lilian',76,3,[12,25]),
 new Robot('Ernest',100,1,[11,14]),
 new Robot('Juliette',87,3,[2,17]),
];

//boucle
 robots.forEach(function(robot) {
 robot.sePresenter();
 robot.seDeplacer();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding, you just want a loop with a random limit:

```
var limit = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1; // 1, 2, or 3
for (var x = 0; x < limit; ++x) {
    // Call your function
}
```

Or the decrement version:

```
for (var x = Math.floor(Math.random() * 3) + 1;; x > 0; --x) {
    // Call your function
}
```

Comment: Yeah, that's how I understood the question as well. Quite certain this is what the OP is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First get the 'type' of movement and save it:

```
var movement = Math.random();
```

Then wrap your 'Deplacer'-code in a loop:

```
var i, l;
for (i = 0, l = Math.round(Math.random() * 3); i < l; i += 1) {
  if (movement < 0.5) {
    // mouvement sur l'axe x
  } else {
    // mouvement sur l'axe y
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a simple loop, that you can of course move to a separate function to make it cleaner.

```js
// Objet Robot
function Robot(nick, pv, maxSpeed, position) {
  this.nick = nick;
  this.pv = pv;
  this.maxSpeed = maxSpeed;
  this.position = position;
};

function random(max, min) {
  return parseInt((Math.random() * (max - min + 1)), 10) + min;
}

//Méthode présentation des robots
Robot.prototype.sePresenter = function() {
  console.log("Bonjour je m'appelle " + this.nick + ". J'ai " + this.pv + " points de vie." + " Je me déplace à " + this.maxSpeed + " cases par seconde. Je suis à la case de coordonnées " + this.position);
};
Robot.prototype.seDeplacer = function() {
  if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
    // mouvement sur l'axe x
  } else {
    // mouvement sur l'axe y
  }
  var dx = (Math.random() * this.maxSpeed * 2) - this.maxSpeed;
  this.position[0] += dx;

  console.log("J'avancer vers " + this.position)
};

//Variables array
var robots = [
  new Robot('Maurice', 95, 2, [5, 8]),
  new Robot('Lilian', 76, 3, [12, 25]),
  new Robot('Ernest', 100, 1, [11, 14]),
  new Robot('Juliette', 87, 3, [2, 17]),
];

//boucle
robots.forEach(function(robot) {
  robot.sePresenter();
  for (var i = 0; i < random(3, 1); ++i) {
    robot.seDeplacer();
  }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you will still need to use setInterval but you could still make it trigger randomly:

```
setInterval(function () {
    if(Math.floor(Math.random() * 255) + 1 > 127) {
        robots.forEach(function (robot) {
            robot.seDeplacer();
        });
    }
}, 250);
```

This would occur randomly, only when the Math.random() function returns greater than 127

Comment: *"I don't want a timer or something like that..."*